# Making an XY line chart in Unity with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, charts

I have to create a XY line Chart in Unity. Are there any good assets or libraries for achieving this?

Rendering lines and points seems to me to be an overcomplicated solution for such a simple task. I tried to solve this issue with different UI Elements - but not successful.

Comment: Try this: https://assetstore.unity.com/lists/graphs-charts-51860

Answer (score 1):

Use Unity.UI.Extensions and their LineRenderer